# PLS-00307 when subprograms differ only in type parameters (RAW vs VARCHAR2)

Tags: oracle, plsql, overloading

I have a package with two methods:

```
create or replace package demo
as
  function overloaded(p_in varchar2)
  return pls_integer;

  function overloaded(p_in raw)
  return pls_integer;
end;
/

create or replace package body demo
as
  function overloaded(p_in raw)
  return pls_integer
  is
  begin
    return 1;
  end;

  function overloaded(p_in varchar2)
  return pls_integer
  is
  begin
    return 2;
  end;
end;
/
```

It compiles without any errors, but I cannot call either method, as in both cases I get error `PLS-00307: too many declarations match this call`. Why does this happen with `RAW` and `VARCHAR2`? How can I work around this limitation? Is giving different names to my subprograms the only way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-47D5A50E-7AAF-4C80-A06A-37593EA2526A):

> PL/SQL lets you overload nested subprograms, package subprograms, and type methods. You can use the same name for several different subprograms if their formal parameters differ in name, number, order, or data type family.

And according to the [the appendix that refers to](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-predefined-data-types.html#GUID-1D28B7B6-15AE-454A-8134-F8724551AE8B), '`varchar2` and `raw` are both members of the `char` data type family.

You can give the subprograms different names, but you can also change the name and order of the formal parameters; in this case as there is only one parameter that means you can change only the name(s):

```
create or replace package demo
as
  function overloaded(p_in_vc varchar2)
  return pls_integer;

  function overloaded(p_in_raw raw)
  return pls_integer;
end;
/
```

(and the same change in the body of course); and then call with [named notation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-A5DA8CF5-1BCC-4ABE-9B68-DB593FF1D2CC) for the actual parameters:

```
select demo.overloaded(p_in_vc=>'test') from dual;

DEMO.OVERLOADED(P_IN_VC=>'TEST')
--------------------------------
                               2

select demo.overloaded(p_in_raw=>'AABB') from dual;

DEMO.OVERLOADED(P_IN_RAW=>'AABB')
---------------------------------
                                1
```

Comment: I'll never understand the reasoning behind raw and varchar being in the same type family, especially since Oracle uses the worst possible implicit conversion between them.